# Spring XML Configuration Files not being loaded into Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Issue: Beans from multiple configuration XMLs are not being pulled in to Spring Boot.

Code:

```
 package com.test.application.context.java;

 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

 @Configuration
 @ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
 public class XmlConfiguration {

 }
```

The applicationContext.xml has the following resource & bean imports:

```
<import resource="classpath*:proxy.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:dao.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:handler.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:core.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:schemas.xml" />
<bean id="applicationContextHolder" 
class="com.test.spring.ApplicationContextHolder" />
<bean id="apiHandler" class="com.test.handler.ApiHandler" />
```

The 2 Beans which are explicity called are found, but the beans in each imported xml are not being pulled in.  Am I improperly importing these configuration XMLs?  I seem to be following all of the examples I've found up until this point.

Comment: are all xml in the same level or some package? all are your beans? or some are in jars?

Comment: The other bean configurations/xmls are in different modules

Comment: check their path, you should specify /com/package/dao.xml if it is not on top